# Hold button howto

Tags: java, android, button, delayed-execution

I need a hold button in android java. I tried with setOnTouchListener and it worked. But it is little too fast.
Is it possible to make the button slower, and to send value when the hold is let off for the same button?

```
    buttonB.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        yon=",B,";
        set++;

        if(set==360) set = 0;


        sensorView2.setText(set);
        packet+=set+yon;

        mConnectedThread.write(packet);
```

Answer (score 0):

for holding button, maybe you can use [setOnLongClickListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnLongClickListener) instead of OnTouchListener

Comment: I tried setOLongClickListener, but its do  what setOnClicklistener do and only 1 time